# Forget password functionality for not login user using azure graph API

Tags: azure, httprequest, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to add an option for a user which is "forget password"
here the user can change their password (no login)

there is any way to do this using azure graph API using HTTP request
if any then what configuration I required and validate user?

Comment: I dont think you can do that, all aad graph api references here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/api-catalog

Answer (score 0):

currently, we do not have this feature 
as per reference from [enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/309eed08-1ea7-4d08-a0e3-76b9f01ad579/user-forget-password-using-azure-graph-api-https-request?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

[enter link description here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/309eed08-1ea7-4d08-a0e3-76b9f01ad579/user-forget-password-using-azure-graph-api-https-request?forum=WindowsAzureAD)